# Vue, multiple instances of same component handling events in some strange way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use two instances of the same components.
I implemented two methods which should be called when one of the two instances emit an event.
The only difference between the two instances is that instance1 should call method1 and instance2 should call method2.

It happens that method1 is always called, no matter which components emits the event.

Am I missing something?

Here a short example of what I'm doing

**CustomComponent**

```html
<template>
....// Some code that at a certain point calls myMethod
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    myMethod () {
      this.$emit('picture-taken')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Page where I'm using CustomComponent**

```html
<template>
  <custom-component @picture-taken="func1" />
  <custom-component @picture-taken="func2" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    func1() {
      debugger
      //It always ends up here
    },
    func2() {
      debugger
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Here, what you wrote is "in case of a `@picture-taken` event, call `func1` and `func2`". Since you do have the listener on both components, both methods will be called. This is totally working as expected.

Comment: But there are two separate instances which should live independently of one another. If I do something on the first instance it should call func1, otherwise func2. It always calls the first one (not both)

Comment: Their data and lifecycles do live in themselves. But here, you do listen to an event in parent's scope, on top of that you do have a `debugger` which is probably blocking the code so that it does not reach `func2`.

Comment: In case it helps, I also tried passing a function as a prop to the component and then, instead of emitting an event, I called that function. Same result, only func1 gets called. func2 never gets called, debugger or not.

Comment: In Vue, you should not pass functions inside of props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of code works for your use-case.

`parent page`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <child :id="1" @picture-taken="callSpecificFunction"></child>
    <child :id="2" @picture-taken="callSpecificFunction"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  auth: false,
  methods: {
    callSpecificFunction(id) {
      console.log('id emitted', id)
      this[`function${id}`]()
    },
    function1() {
      console.log('function1 called')
    },
    function2() {
      console.log('function2 called')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`Child.vue`

```html
<template>
  <button @click="emitPlease">please do emit for id {{ id }}</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    emitPlease() {
      this.$emit('picture-taken', this.id)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: it does not work. I'm starting to think of some bug or issue with the vue/nuxt version I'm using. It seems not to be passing any prop correctly. Inside "child" the prop this.id is always "1".

Comment: @sangio90 what I've linked to you is working and passed either id `1` or `2`. You probably had a typo or alike. Please double-check your code.

Comment: It was my fault but it was not that easy to find. It turned out that inside the component there was an <input type="file"> with a fixed id so I had 2 input with the same id and thus a random behavior.Now it works flawlessly with the code from my first example. Thanks a lot for your time :-)